# Appending Name based on Min and Max datetime

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have Event_No, Events, Date Range in my table like below.

```
[Event_No, Events, Date Range
       1     PR    2/6/2018 12:01:00 AM
       1     PR    2/6/2018 12:02:00 AM
       1     PR    2/6/2018 12:03:00 AM
       1     RR    2/6/2018 12:04:00 AM
       1     RR    2/6/2018 12:05:00 AM
       1     RR    2/6/2018 12:06:00 AM
       1     SR    2/6/2018 12:07:00 AM
       1     SR    2/6/2018 12:08:00 AM
       1     SR    2/6/2018 12:09:00 AM
       2     PR    2/6/2018 01:01:00 AM
       2     PR    2/6/2018 01:02:00 AM
       2     PR    2/6/2018 01:03:00 AM
       2     RR    2/6/2018 01:04:00 AM
       2     RR    2/6/2018 01:05:00 AM
       2     RR    2/6/2018 01:06:00 AM
       2     SR    2/6/2018 01:07:00 AM
       2     SR    2/6/2018 01:08:00 AM
       2     SR    2/6/2018 01:09:00 AM
```

I need to show Min datetime respective Event name with 'IN'(a concatenation of (Event-'IN'))and  Max datetime respective Event with Out(a concatenation of (Event-'Out')). I need My Final Output like below

```
Event_No   Events            Date Range      EventInOut
       1     PR    2/6/2018 12:01:00 AM       PR-IN
       1     PR    2/6/2018 12:03:00 AM       PR-OUT
       1     RR    2/6/2018 12:04:00 AM       RR-IN
       1     RR    2/6/2018 12:06:00 AM       RR-OUT
       1     SR    2/6/2018 12:07:00 AM       SR-IN
       1     SR    2/6/2018 12:09:00 AM       SR-OUT
       2     PR    2/6/2018 01:01:00 AM       PR-IN
       2     PR    2/6/2018 01:03:00 AM       PR-OUT
       2     RR    2/6/2018 01:04:00 AM       RR-IN 
       2     RR    2/6/2018 01:06:00 AM       RR-OUT
       2     SR    2/6/2018 01:07:00 AM       SR-IN
       2     SR    2/6/2018 01:09:00 AM       SR-OUT
```

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a gaps and islands problem.

```
select event_no, date,
       min(date), max(date)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by event_no order by date) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by event_no, event order by date) as seqnum_e
      from t
     ) t
group by event_no, event;
```

This puts the values on one row, which might meet your needs.

You can also use `lead()` and `lag()`:

```
select t.*,
       (event || '-' || (case when prev_event is null then 'IN' else 'OUT' end))
from (select t.*,
             lag(event) over (partition by event_no order by date) as prev_event,
             lead(event) over (partition by event_no order by date) as next_event
      from t
     ) t
where prev_event is null or next_event is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should get you the results....

```
create table events(event_no int, events varchar(10),date_range timestamp)

insert into events
select 1,'PR',timestamp '2/6/2018 12:01:00 AM' union all
select 1,'PR',timestamp '2/6/2018 12:02:00 AM' union all
select 1,'PR',timestamp '2/6/2018 12:03:00 AM' union all
select 1,'RR',timestamp '2/6/2018 12:04:00 AM' union all
select 1,'RR',timestamp '2/6/2018 12:05:00 AM' union all
select 1,'RR',timestamp '2/6/2018 12:06:00 AM' union all
select 1,'SR',timestamp '2/6/2018 12:07:00 AM' union all
select 1,'SR',timestamp '2/6/2018 12:08:00 AM' union all
select 1,'SR',timestamp '2/6/2018 12:09:00 AM' union all
select 2,'PR',timestamp '2/6/2018 01:01:00 AM' union all
select 2,'PR',timestamp '2/6/2018 01:02:00 AM' union all
select 2,'PR',timestamp '2/6/2018 01:03:00 AM' union all
select 2,'RR',timestamp '2/6/2018 01:04:00 AM' union all
select 2,'RR',timestamp '2/6/2018 01:05:00 AM' union all
select 2,'RR',timestamp '2/6/2018 01:06:00 AM' union all
select 2,'SR',timestamp '2/6/2018 01:07:00 AM' union all
select 2,'SR',timestamp '2/6/2018 01:08:00 AM' union all
select 2,'SR',timestamp '2/6/2018 01:09:00 AM'

 with data
  as (
 select *
       ,row_number() over(partition by event_no,events order by date_range) as rnk
       ,date_range - (row_number() over(partition by event_no,events order by date_range)* interval '1 minute' ) as col_range
  from events
      )
     ,iterim_data
     as(
select *
       ,row_number() over(partition by col_range order by date_range asc) as rnk_asc
       ,row_number() over(partition by col_range order by date_range desc) as rnk_desc
  from data
       )
select event_no,events,date_range
       ,case when rnk_asc=1 then concat(events,'-IN')
             when rnk_desc=1 then concat(events,'-OUT')
        end             
  from iterim_data
where (rnk_asc=1 or rnk_desc=1)
```

db fiddle link
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=00304c5f260a199a99c8d43bd351c3a1